# Convert 2017-01-13T06:00:00Z time format to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time

I'm trying to convert time formats.  The database table has time stored in a VARCHAR(50) column in the format of "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ssZ".  When running a query, I want the time formatted as "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss".  (I don't care about time zone adjustment.)  I don't understand why GETDATE with the style 120 returns what I want, but when I use the field name it does nothing.

```
SELECT  
  PlateEffectiveFrom as Value_In_Table, 
  STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(33),PlateEffectiveFrom, 120),20,4,'') as 'Gets_Rid_of_Z',  
  CONVERT(varchar(33), PlateEffectiveFrom, 120) AS Does_Nothing,
  CONVERT(varchar(33), GETDATE(), 120) AS Format_I_Want
FROM    dbo.TVLTagDetails13
WHERE   ID = 5
```

Returns:

```
Value_In_Table          Gets_Rid_of_Z         Does_Nothing           Format_I_Want
2008-03-12T06:00:00Z    2008-03-12T06:00:00   2008-03-12T06:00:00Z   2019-01-08 11:16:41
```

Comment: SQL Server? You say `PlateEffectiveFrom` is a varchar (which is terrible in itself), but you treat it as if it were a datetime already. Convert it to a datetime first.

Comment: Thank you.  The following does what I need.  `CONVERT(varchar(33), CAST(PlateEffectiveFrom AS datetime), 120) AS Format_I_Want,`  That said, I'm not a developer.  Why is varchar terrible?  What would I use instead?

Comment: You'd use a string data type (varchar, nvarchar, ...) for strings, a numeric data type (int, decimal, ..) for numbers, and a date/time data type (date, datetime, ...) for dates and times. Using the appropriate data type allows you to compare values, get the minimum and maximum value etc. Here is the docs on data types in T-SQL (e.g. SQL Server): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Thorsten  Thank you.  That helps.  I was able to be more specific on a number of my fields.

Comment: @Andrew Where at all possible, you should do formatting of output in the front-end of the application, which will typically be written in code which has easier-to-use functions for the purpose.

Comment: "The database table has time stored in a VARCHAR(50) " There's your problem right there. You should store time-zone aware datetime values in a `DateTimeOffset` data type, not in a `varchar`.

Comment: "Why is varchar terrible?" - because someone can equally easily store "next tuesday" or "France" in a column where you're expecting to find a datetime. Even if you have an immensely complex check constraint on the column that attempts to constrain the possible values to "valid looking" datetime data (unlikely given it's oversize) will it really have enough logic to prevent someone inserting the 30th February?

Comment: @Andrew it's not only that varchar is *terrible* for storing dates. The format you use is already supported by the `datetimeoffset` type - ISO8601 at UTC+0. The correct type for that is `datetimeoffset`. SQL Server already provides functions to handle timezone conversions and conversion from UTC to local time etc

Comment: @Andrew problem #2 - what offset do you want the result to be in? Do you want UTC or local time? What is your local offset *at the values date*? You have to take care of summer time. The solution is to **fix the bug** by converting the `nvarchar` column to a `datetimeoffset`. If all values follow the ISO8601 format the change will be trivial. If not, you have data corruption issues already

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem would be to change the data type of the column to `DateTime2` if you don't need the time zone data, or `DateTimeOffset` if you need the time zone data.
Assuming this can't be done, what you do is a simple string manipulation to get from `"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ssZ"` to `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss"`:

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(PlateEffectiveFrom, 'T', ' '), 19) AS Format_I_Want
FROM dbo.TVLTagDetails13
WHERE ID = 5
```

Also, following the conversation in the comments - a must read: Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)